# Scala Case class copy member of parent trait when calling copy()

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-macros, case-class

I am using case classes for models in an ORM. Each model has an id, but the id shouldn't be publicly accessible. So I have a parent trait

```
trait WithId {
  private var id: Long = 0
}
```

and a lot of case classes (the models) inheriting from it

```
case class C1(a: Int, b: String) extends WithId
case class C2(...) extends WithId
...
```

Now, if someone calls copy() on a case class, it doesn't copy the id with it, but sets it to 0.

```
val c1 = C1(3, "bla")
//Set c1.id to a value != 0
val c2 = c1.copy(b="bla2")
//c1.id !=0, but c2.id = 0
```

I want it to copy the id as well.

Since I have a lot of these case classes, I'd prefer to have as few code as possible in the case classes themselves. So implementing a copy() method in each case class would be a lot of boilerplate code.

Is there a way to implement something in the trait that makes copy() also copy the id? Maybe something using macros? Or is there another way I didn't think about at all?

**edit**:

I could override the id field in each case class like

```
case class C1(a: Int, b: String, protected var id: Long)
```

Then it would be copied. But that also is boilerplate code I have to write per case class and it's hard to explain why you have to add an id field to a case class although you never notice it or can use it anywhere else when using the case class. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I can't help you with an answer, but I'd recommend to put in some effort and refactor your code. Having an addition (mutable) field in a case class is a stinky code smell. E.g. two instances with different `id` could be equal.

Comment: @poroszd - Although mutability can be a problem, it is not at all difficult to assign two instances the wrong IDs immutably also.  The problem with mutable ID is that you might count on it to be stable when it is not.

Comment: The id is not accessible from outside of the ORM framework. I have to make it mutable inside, since ORM models have id=0 when initialized and this id is updated once the object is added to the database. But you're right, I should override the == operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd add an ID-carrying token:

```
class IdToken private[myPackage] (val id: Int) {
  override def equals(a: Any) = a match {
    case tok: IdToken => id == tok.id
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = id.hashCode ^ 0x157135
  override def toString = ""
}
object IdToken {
  private var lastId = 0
  private[myPackage] def next = { lastId += 1; new IdToken(lastId) }
}
```

Since the constructor is private to your package, nobody else but you can create these tokens.

Then you write your trait as

```
trait WithID { protected def idToken: IdToken }
```

and

```
case class C1(a: Int, b: String, protected val idToken: IdToken = IdToken.next) extends WithID {
  def checkId = idToken.id
}
```

(where you only need `checkId` for the test below) so you can

```
scala> C1(5, "fish")
res1: C1 = C1(5,fish,)

scala> res1.copy(a = 3)
res2: C1 = C1(3,fish,)

scala> res1.checkId == res2.checkId
res3: Boolean = true
```

But you can't access the token from outside code because the `val` is `protected`.

Hopefully that is good enough encapsulation.

Comment: Thank you. This is the best solution I saw so far. But I was hoping to avoid per-case-class code, since I'm going to have a lot of them. See my edit above.

Comment: @Heinzi - Your only other option is a global object registry which a newly-created object checks and pulls its ID from.  I do not recommend this.  Well, that and macros.  You can do a lot with macros, but it's not at all straightforward, and until you end up with a working solution it can be hard to tell if a solution exists.